RestSharp.RestResponse.Content is truncated in C#
Receiving below truncated response where as the rawbyte has full data while calling a Rest API in c# using V112.1.0.
RestSharp.RestResponse}
    Content: "[{\"ClientId\":\"11030xxxx\",\"tradingSymbol\":\"NIFTY-Dec2024-23850-CE\",\"securityId\":\"41689\",\"positionType\":\"CLOSED\",\"exchangeSegment\":\"NSE_FNO\",\"productType\":\"MARGIN\",\"buyAvg\":68.5,\"costPrice\":68.5,\"buyQty\":100,\"sellAvg\":70.3,\"sellQty\":100,\"netQty\":0,\"realizedProfit\":180.0,\"unrealizedProfit\":0.0,\"rbiReferenceRate\":1.0,\"multiplier\":1,\"carryForwardBuyQty\":0,\"carryForwardSellQty\":0,\"carryForwardBuyValue\":0.0,\"carryForwardSellValue\":0.0,\"dayBuyQty\":100,\"daySellQty\":100,\"dayBuyValue\":6850.0,\"daySellValue\":7030.0,\"drvExpiryDate\":\"2024-12-26 14:30:00\",\"drvOptionType\":\"CALL\",\"drvStrikePrice\":23850.0,\"crossCurrency\":false},{\"dhanClientId\":\"11030xxxx\",\"tradingSymbol\":\"PSUBNKBEES\",\"securityId\":\"15032\",\"positionType\":\"LONG\",\"exchangeSegment\":\"NSE_EQ\",\"productType\":\"CNC\",\"buyAvg\":73.95,\"costPrice\":73.95,\"buyQty\":50,\"sellAvg\":0.0,\"sellQty\":0,\"netQty\":50,\"realizedProfit\":0.0,\"unrealizedProfit\":-29.5,
\"rbiReferenceRate\":1.0,\"multiplier\":1,\"carryForwardBuyQty\":0,\"carryForwardSellQty\":0,\"carryForwardBuyValue\":0.0,\"carryForward..."
    ContentEncoding: ""
    ContentLength: -1
    ContentType: "application/json"
    Cookies: Count = 0
    ErrorException: null
    ErrorMessage: null
    Headers: Count = 5
    RawBytes: {byte[1203]}
    Request: {RestSharp.RestRequest}
    ResponseStatus: Completed
    ResponseUri: {https://api.xxxx.co/v2/positions}
    Server: ""
    StatusCode: OK
    StatusDescription: ""

Please support to fix this issue.
The full Content value suppose to be (RawBytes decoded)
[{"ClientId":"11030xxxx","tradingSymbol":"NIFTY-Dec2024-23850-CE","securityId":"41689","positionType":"CLOSED","exchangeSegment":"NSE_FNO","productType":"MARGIN","buyAvg":68.5,"costPrice":68.5,"buyQty":100,"sellAvg":70.3,"sellQty":100,"netQty":0,"realizedProfit":180.0,"unrealizedProfit":0.0,"rbireferenceRate":1.0,"multiplier":1,"carryForwardBuyQty":0,"carryForwardSellQty":0,"carryForwardBuyValue":0.0,"carryForwardSellValue":0.0,"dayBuyQty":100,"daySellQty":100,"dayBuyValue":6850.0,"daySellValue":7030.0,"drvExpiryDate":"2024-12-26 14:30:00","drvOptionType":"CALL","drvStrikePrice":23850.0,crossCurrency":false},{"ClientId":"11030xxxx","tradingSymbol":"PSUBNKBEES","securityId":"15032","positionType":"LONG","exchangeSegment":"NSE_EQ","productType":"CNC","buyAvg":73.95,"costPrice":73.95,"buyQty":50,"sellAvg":0.0,"sellQty":0,"netQty":50,"realizedProfit":0.0,"unrealizedProfit":-29.5,"rbiReferenceRate":1.0,"multiplier":1,"carryForwardBuyQty":0,"carryForwardSellQty":0,"carryForwardBuyValue":0.0,"carryForwardSellValue":0.0,"dayBuyQty":50,"daySellQty":0,"dayBuyValue":3697.5,"daySellValue":0.0,"drvExpiryDate":"0001-01-01","drvOptionType":"NA","drvStrikePrice":0.0,"crossCurrecy":false}]


Have you tried using Fiddler (or other tool) to see the actual response message?

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]

@Ricardo Pere. Fiddler captures the full response. Its either the restsharp or the C# causing the issue.

This is not a real issue as I noticed today. The truncated string is from VS debugging window scope only. When checked the RestResponse.Content, full response is available.
